# AuthzDBDQuery allow to use stored procedure call instead of select?

Tags: apache, apr

can AuthzDBDQuery call a stored procedure instead? I'm trying to get this working but i'm given an error AH01652: authz_dbd, in groups query for user@user.COM

The error is coming from authz_dbd.c authz_dbd_group_query method because the call to apr_dbd_pvselect is returning 0.

Comment: Please could you try to reformulate your question explaining where you want to do, what did you write, and what situation you are in ?

Comment: per the documentation at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_dbd.html we can deny certain users access to a website by using 
Require dbd-group team
      AuthzDBDQuery "SELECT group FROM authz WHERE user = %s"

what I want to do is beable to write
Require dbd-group team
      AuthzDBDQuery "Call my_stored_proc(%s)"